# Getting firebase.User.uid without provider login

Tags: gwt, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my GWT application, I have developed user authentication using `firebase.auth.Auth`. My UI presents Google, Facebook and Twitter buttons and the user chooses one of them and finishes login using `firebase.auth.Auth.signInWithRedirect(provider)`. It works fine.

Now, for the subsequent logins for the same user in the same browser, I would like to get rid of the above UI presenting the three provider buttons. I would like the show the application screen straight away. There does not seem to be any way of doing this. The API seems to force calling `firebase.auth.Auth.signInWithRedirect(provider`).

Can someone help in this regard ? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of describing the code, can you reproduce the problem in a minimal, complete snippet? That will make it much easier to see what you talk about and thus help you.